# CSS Dim overlay: Shining through

Tags: css, z-index

I have a dim overlay, and want certain elements to poke through. It seems a higher z-index is not enough: I must set `position: relative/absolute`. Is there any way to avoid this? See my basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hSYU2/. As soon as you remove the `position`, the circle disappears.

An explanation of the mechanics would be swell.

Comment: i am just trying to figure out what you are trying to do here. what do you mean by 'poke through'? do you want it to end up something like this [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/9A6rh/1/)?

Comment: Yes, why does that work and mine does not?

Comment: in your first example, the reason the circle disappears is because it is white. so it is a white circle on a white background with a half opaque overlay. Look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/hSYU2/4/ - it is the same as your first one with a black circle without the positioning

Comment: Yes, but that black circle is partially obscured by the opacity: 0.5 of the #dim. I want it to be as if there were no opacity overlay on it.

Comment: right, so you want my other solution. In that one, I just placed the #circle div inside the #dim div and removed the positioning

Comment: I like that, it's very simple. Unfortunately I can't remove the dim positioning (the website is complicated so I have to deal with the elements I'm injecting). I suppose I could move it above <div id="dim /> in the DOM tree to make it show.

Comment: @Jasie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1649/discussion-between-quagland-and-jasie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index),

```
'z-index'  
     Value:         auto | <integer> | inherit
     Initial:       auto
     Applies to:    positioned elements
```

`z-index` only applies to positioned elements (i.e: fixed, absolute or relative), so no, there is no way to avoid it.